# WeChat SandBox API Configuration Failed

Tags: php, configuration, wechat

I'm getting the "Configuration Failed" pop up after submitting my URL and Token in the WeChat sandbox environment. Could anyone suggest ways to debug or find a solution? Here are the details:

- running a Heroku server and using the heroku generated URL.
- pushed the sample code found in the documentation [here](http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Message_Authentication)
- followed the youtube tutorial, copied the code and tried that as well.

> ```
> <?php
>
> $data[] = 'Test123';
> $data[] = $_GET['timestamp'];
> $data[] = $_GET['nonce'];
>
> asort($data);
>
> $strData = '';
> $d = '';
> $authString = '';
> foreach($data as $d){
> $authString .= $d;
> }
>
>
> //verify the signture 
> if(sha1($authString) == $_GET[signature]){
> //check if the echostr
>     if(!empty($_GET['echostr'])){
>     echo $_GET['echostr'];
>     die();
> }else{
> //logic goes here
>       $return = '<xml>
>                 <ToUserName><![CDATA['.$toUser.']]></ToUserName>
>                 <FromUserName><![CDATA['.$fromUser.']]></FromUserName>
>                 <CreateTime>'.time().'</CreateTime>
>                 <MsgType><![CDATA[text]]></MsgType>
>                 <Content><![CDATA['.$text.']]></Content>
>                 <FuncFlag>0</FuncFlag>
>                 </xml>';
>                 echo $return;
>      }
> }else{
>      die('You are not supposed to be here');
> }
>
>
> ?>
> ```

- checked the logs and found that its working fine but shows no activity when I submit the URL and token on WeChat sandbox.
- have tried different variations of URL, from using the root URL to finishing with the php file ie xxxx/responder.php
- Token submitted matches Token used in code.
- Uploading raw php to the server, hijacked the heroku php [hello world app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php) with the documentation code or youtube code.

The code itself comes straight from the WeChat Docs or the Youtube Video. Please let me know if I could provide any additional information.

Any advice, tips or hints would be really appreciated.

Comment: I also tried using hosting account. URL http://smartaverage.com/wechat/first/first_app.php with no success. Again when looking at the raw access logs of the application server, after a URL and TOKEN submission, which show no record of any request originating from the WeChat servers or containing any of the four expected GET parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check. The sandbox environment was broken for International. This should be resolved now. Please test again